# react upload to s3 deadtime issue

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm suffering from inability to get `chunk.js` (main.somenumber.chunk.js) when uploading to s3 from local.

When the speed of the upload is severely hampered, static hosting fails with `unexpected token <" error`.

If the upload executes fast enough, this does not occur. For the fast upload, I set TTL at 0s.

How can I prevent my react app starts from rendering completely uploaded chunk, instead of hurriedly trying to show what's not ready yet?

It seems like asset-manifest.json includes all necessary directories and if this file is uploaded later, then I hope this problem will no longer bother, but I'm not sure that's a proper way worthy of spending time.!

Comment: So the site is hosted on S3? Do I understand correctly that the problem is that you're trying to access the site before all of the chunks have finished uploading to S3?

Comment: the site is hosted on s3 (not nextjs). And yes, while I am uploading to s3, somebody would access the website with loading failure. So I am trying to find the way to root out the deadzone here!

Comment: If this is in the context of deploying an updated site, you could upload the chunks _before_ uploading the updated HTML and manifest files. Is this really a big issue though? Surely the chunks don't take _that_ long to upload?